# jQuery - How to check if input contains only cyrillic letters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how i can check if input with specific id contains only cyrillic letters in it.

I want simple jQuery function to check the input for cyrillic letters and when there are only cyrillic letters to give alert `Everything is COOL :D` and when there are not only cyrillic letters to give alert `We've got a problem Houston!`.

This is a simple example of what i want to do this function.

Can you please help me out ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't know what to try about that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp like:

```
/[а-яА-Я]/
```

Here is an example:

```
var str1 = "Привет";
var str2 = "Hello";

var patt = /[а-яА-Я]/g;

console.log( patt.test(str1) );
// will log true

console.log( patt.test(str2) );
// will log false
```

[Read about regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: How will look the complete function ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Tony, first try it,  and then, if you have a problem, come back and post another question

Comment: I don't know how to use Regexp, that is why i ask. Thanks :)

Comment: @TonyStark [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) then you will know and be able to ask better questions.  You don't really want other people to do your work for you, do you?

Comment: @TonyStark check updates, hopefully this will shed some light

Comment: @SteveH. -- I bet he does.  I know I do.